# Use knockout extenders to add warning if value is negative

Tags: knockout.js

I've gotten an requirement that all numeric columns in our knockout grid should have red color if they are negative to warn the user.

I could do it with standard bindings, but it would add a lot of code to the viewmodel and view.

I use the knockout validation framework and they use extenders to add validation.

I want to do the same, I've looked at the extender examples, but they require you do add elements to the view, Somehow the validation framework works with only extenders, how can I do the same? My goal is to only need something like this to add the warning

```
this.accountBalance = ko.observable(data.AccountBalance).extend({ warnIfNegative: true });
```

**Update:** I did this after looking at the validation framework, what I dont like is that you need to override each binding to get it to work, for example i want this both for text and value binding

```
(function () {

    ko.extenders.negativeValueWarning = function (target, option) {
        target.hasWarning = ko.observable();

        function warn(newValue) {
            target.hasWarning(newValue < 0 ? true : false);
        }

        warn(target());

        target.subscribe(warn);

        return target;
    };


    var init = ko.bindingHandlers.text.init;
    ko.bindingHandlers.text.init = function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        if (init)
            init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (value.hasWarning) {
            ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { negativeValueWarning: value.hasWarning });
        }
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.negativeValueWarning = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var warn = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (warn)
                $(element).addClass("negative-warning");
            else
                $(element).removeClass("negative-warning");
        }
    };
} ());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this, what do you guys think?

http://jsfiddle.net/ZYyEw/25/

**Update: Using computed instead of subscribe**

```
ko.extenders.negativeValueWarning = function (target, option) {
    target.hasWarning = ko.observable();

    function warn(newValue) {
        if(newValue && newValue.substring) {
            newValue = parseFloat(newValue);
        }
        target.hasWarning(newValue < 0 ? true : false);
    }

    warn(target());

    target.subscribe(warn);

    return target;
};
```

Comment: Interesting idea using your override function to change the default behavior of text and value bindings.  However, from a recent and very painful experience, changing the default behavior of existing bindings can easily cause un-intended problems in a very large project.

Comment: This is how the official validation framework is doing it, but yes, its a bit sad that you have to override the bindings. I would rather that the extender framework in ko gave me all the elements that's subscribed to the observable conneted with the extension.

Comment: What "Official validation framework" are you referring to?  knockout itself doesn't concern itself with validation.

Comment: That's what I thought.  There is no Official Validation code for knockout.  This is a plug-in for knockout written by individuals not part of the knockout team.  That being said, it is a very good framework.

Comment: Ok but its probably the framework you use if you want native validation in knockout, and they do it this way, but I dont see any other way right now. Would like if RP Niemeyer or someone could confirm this to be a ok solution. I have jasmine tests for all VM's but they do not test the bindings

Comment: Agree fully with your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this would be best via a custom binder.  For info on them, see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

I've created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/DzQMX/ that gives you what you want.  The "trick" in this example is that I'm reusing the knockout value binding to handle all the real work.  I then added code to control how the control is displayed.  It is basically merging your extender with a data binder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it seems, that this does not work. Nothing happened when i put negative value in textbox.